# Unit test (connect to Analysis Services) fails on TeamCity - but not on VS 2010 on the same machine

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, unit-testing, teamcity, business-intelligence

I've written some code that runs an MDX query against an SQL Server Analysis services. Unit tests on my dev machine work fine - however the TeamCity installation also runs the unit tests and only the ones connecting to the analysis services give an exception stating:

```
Test method GetNumCompaniesPerIndustryTest threw exception: 
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnectionException: The connection either timed out or was lost. 
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

This is the error I was getting before when my connection string wasn't right. The weird thing is that the server with TeamCity also has a VS 2010 installation so I can open the solution form the /buildAgent/work folder and run the unit tests. All tests work fine from VS - so there's no connection problem it seems.
Connection string is in a settings file inside the DLL in application scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the QA environment was running in a different Application Pool with corresponding user. I had to add this user to the BI database users.

Answer (score 0):

It may be permissions. What account is your TeamCity build agent running under?  Is this the same account you are logged into the machine with?  What type of authentication are you using with the services?

Answer (score 0):

The error "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" is often caused by the "TCP Chimney offloading" setting on your analysis server. See [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cindygross/archive/2009/10/22/sql-server-and-tcp-chimney.aspx) for more information about it.

To switch off the setting run the following in an command shell on your analysis server:

```
Netsh int ip set chimney DISABLED
```